# How to serve HTTP header 404 with a static html page?

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, seo, http-headers, http-status-code-404

How to return HTTP header 404 Not found and still show a static html page?
I have
   `ErrorDocument 404 mysite.com/searchmysite/index.html` 
in .htaccess.
But apparently this is not good for seo.

Similar not answered questions:
[Can I change the page's HTML status code on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508913/are-i-can-serve-the-html-page-with-404-status-code-using-javascript) and [404 header - HTTP 1.0 or 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1)

Comment: Both questions you've referred to seem to me very much answered...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to send the `404` error code as part of your own, custom HTML page that doesn't involve `ErrorDoccument`,  you can send the `404` header using **Server-Side Code** like PHP, for example, using `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`. You must send this **before any output**, and after sending it, output your custom webpage.

There is also no reason why `ErrorDocument` would be bad for SEO, unless you are worried about the `404` response, in which case, **you do not want to send the `404` header in the first place**.